geom_smooth method: which one to choose?
How can I make sure that I am using a correct line for my plot?
The plot is intended to show how many comments in a social media platform were annotated as "Favoring AR" etc. in which year.
When I use geom_smooth(method = 'lm'...), I get the following:

When I use geom_smooth(method = 'auto'...), I get the following:

I don't really know the differences (lm, glm, gam, loess, rlm...). Could you please make it clear for me if I can use any of those lines in my plot, and if yes, how should I make the selection among these options?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is an underlying statistical question here, but phrasing it in terms of R code inverts principle and practice. For this particular example, more context would surely help e..g are the lower numbers of 2024 largely a side-effect of a  partial year? would log scale help?

@NickCox thanks a lot for your answer! lower numbers in 2024 are due to the fact that the sampling only covered till February 2024. I might actually remove 2024. Looking at the number of comments across different categories, I want to argue that, for example, the second group showed a more dramatic upward trend than others. In this case, is it possible to make use of a trend line? Would loess be ok here?

I can’t helpfully  prejudge the success of loess compared with other methods. First aid for trending data often starts with plotting on logarithmic scale.

The difference between method = 'lm' and method = 'mvgv::gam() (which is probably the default here given your sample size), or any other method, is in the form of the smoothing function you apply. In your example, method = 'lm' fits a linear model, which you see as a straight line. For the default method, a generalized additive model (GAM) fits a wavy-line using smoothing functions.
What method should you use? That depends on what you want to show with the data. If you expect the relationship that is driving patterns in your data to be linear, then you should use method = 'lm'. If you're not sure what the pattern should be, you should use the default and use the smoothing line to help you see the overall pattern in the data through time. If you're not sure what you're trying to show with a smoothing function at all then you shouldn't bother with a geom_smooth at all, and instead just plot the raw data. It's OK to just show the raw data, if that's all you're prepared to talk about.

Thank you very much for your comment!

@berk no problem! you should mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question
